# Question about JavaScript variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, each

Can someone tell me why this alert is empty?

```
var pending_dates = [];
$.getJSON('/ajax/event-json-output.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    pending_dates.push({'event_date' : val.event_date});
    });
});
alert(pending_dates);
```

I can't get my head around this. Am I not declaring `pending_dates` as a global variable, accessible within the each loop? How would one solve this?

Please note that the JSON output is working well. If I would declare pending dates within the `getJSON function` (and alert within that function), it works, but I need to store the data in an array outside of that `getJSON` function.

Thanks for your contributions.

*EDIT*

Thanks to your comments this code is working:

```
    pending_dates = [];
    $.getJSON('/ajax/event-json-output.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            pending_dates.push({'event_date' : val.event_date});
        });
    }).success(function() { alert(pending_dates); })
```

Thanks a lot for your contributions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous call - it returns immediately and then `alert(pending_dates)` is invoked.

However, when that happens, the response from the asynchronous call may not have been received, and hence `pending_dates` may not have been populated.

That is probably why it is empty at the time `alert(pending_dates)` is called.

Answer (score 3):

Your alert is executing before the JSON call has finished.  Remember this JSON it fetched and processed asynchronously, but your alert comes right after it's started.  If you want an alert, then you need to put it at the completion of the getJSON call.

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON` is working asynchronously meaning that whatever you have specified in the callback will be executed eventually but there is no guarantee that will happen by the time you reach `alert('pending_dates')`.

You can verify this by moving `alert('pending_dates')` right after
`pending_dates.push()` (this would result in one alert being displayed for each item it is retrieving).

You can write a function to start working with the data you're retrieving as soon as it is available:

```
var pending_dates = [];
$.getJSON('/ajax/event-json-output.php', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        pending_dates.push({'event_date' : val.event_date});
        doSomething(val.event_date);
    });
});

function doSomething(date) {
    // do something with date
    // like writing it to the page
    // or displaying an alert
}
```

With this you'll be able to work with all the data you get as it becomes available.

Answer (score -2):

Variables are global by default in Javascript - having `var` actually introduces scope. Remove that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doens't work I'm afraid. Any other ideas?

Comment: The variable definition and the alert are in the same scope so this suggestion is not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score -2):

It's more likely that the AJAX response isn't returning any data. Can you try pushing just `'foo'` onto the array, and see if the alert shows anything different?

Comment: It's not more likely. Yes, it's possible, but the problem described is due to the asynchronous nature of the ajax call.